# refactor IF...ELSE into Nested foreach to LINQ

Tags: linq, if-statement, foreach, refactoring

I am having troubles on finding a way to refactor my nested foreach code into a Linq, mostly because it includes an IF-Else clause into it.

Below is a simplified version of my code. How do I include the IF..Else into a linq statement??

I appreciate your suggestions.

```
List<hierarchy> PredomHierarchy;
List<hierarchy> RecesesHierarchy;

foreach x in PredomHierarchy{
foreach y in RecesesHierarchy{  

  if(x.name = y.name){      
    Dosomething(x.name, y.name);                
    } else {        
    DosomethingElse(x.name, y.name);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not (and should not) do `for each` in LINQ. See https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx for an explanation why.

However, what you are doing is a cross product (or carthesian product). You can formulate it like this:

```
from x in PredomHierarchy
from y in RecesesHierarchy
select new {x,y}
```

and then just iterate the result collection:

```
.ToList().ForEach(item => {if (item.x.name == item.y.name) DoSomething(x,y); else DoSomethingElse(x,y);});
```

At that point, you are <strike>probably</strike> better off with the nested `for each` calls, though.

Comment: The `ToList().ForEach` is pointless and inefficient. You could use a `foreach` instead, so exactly what OP is already doing.

Comment: @Tim: Well, yes, isn't that what I just said? Well, let me remove the probably to make it clearer.